# Get player data from XBOX API

Tags: api, xbox, xbox360, xbox-one, xbox-live

I'm currently using https://xapi.us/ to get data from XBOX. We want the data similar to what this site has: https://rocketleague.tracker.network/rocket-league/profile/xbl/Exlzia/overview.

Now I've tried the endpoints `/v2/{xuid}/achievements/{titleId}` and `/v2/{xuid}/game-stats/{titleId}`, but both just doesn't have the same data like above. So I guess my question is if I'm using the right API service for the job?

Answer (score 0):

That website looks like its getting a lot more information than what Xbox API provides.

I suggest you look at using the Rocket League API - https://api.rocketleague.com/